# Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using useRef() instead - with Nextjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-ref

I use Next.js and I'm just trying to add data to the server normally using the `fetch` method and thunk, but I get this error:

> Error: Function components cannot have string refs. We recommend using
> useRef() instead.

addBookForm.jsx:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react'
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { insertBook } from '@/app/redux/Features/bookSlice'
function addBooksForm() {
  // ref
  const title = useRef(null);
  const img = useRef(null);
  const descripition = useRef(null);
  const bookLinke = useRef(null);
  
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handelSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const data = {
      name: title.current.value,
      photo: img.current.value,
      des: descripition.current.value,
      link: bookLinke.current.value
    };

    dispatch(insertBook(data));

    title.current.value = null;
    img.current.value = null;
    descripition.current.value = null;
    bookLinke.current.value = null;
  }

  return (
    <div className="w-full  px-4 bg-white ">
    <div className="max-w-[700px] mx-auto">
      <div className="w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col p-4 my-8 rounded-lg ">
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center py-4">Insert Book</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-6">
            <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
              Title
            </label>
            <input
              type="text"
              className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
              ref={name}
              required
            ></input>
            <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
            Linke of image
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
            ref={img}
            required
          ></input>
            <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
              Description
            </label>
            <textarea
              id="message"
              rows={4}
              className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm mb-4 text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300"
              
              ref={descripition}
              required
            ></textarea>
            <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
            Linke of book
          </label>
          <input
            type="text"
            className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
            ref={bookLinke}
            required
          ></input>
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="text-white bg-[#BDA175] hover:bg-black disabled:bg-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2" 
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  )
}

export default addBooksForm
```

bookSlice:

```js
"use client";
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

export const insertBook = createAsyncThunk(
  "book/insertBook",
  async (bookData, thunkAPI) => {
    const { rejectWithValue } = thunkAPI;

    try {
      const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3005/books", {
        method: "POST",
        body: JSON.stringify(bookData),
        headers: {
          "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
        },
      });
      const data = await res.json();
      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return rejectWithValue(error.message);
    }
  }
);

const bookSlice = createSlice({
  name: "book",
  initialState: { books: [], isLoading: false, error: null },
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {

      // INSERT BOOK
      builder.addCase(insertBook.pending, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = true;
        state.error = null;
      }),
      builder.addCase(insertBook.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.books.push(action.payload);
      }),
      builder.addCase(insertBook.rejected, (state, action) => {
        state.isLoading = false;
        state.error = action.payload;
      });
  },
});

export default bookSlice.reducer;
```

How can I fix that error?

Comment: Probably `ref={name}` since you don't have `name` defined.  Did you mean title?

Comment: In case you missed it or haven't taken the full [tour] yet (*you earn a badge, BTW*), there are 100% completely optional actions one can take after [someone answers](/help/someone-answers) that helps rate and curate content on the site.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue is the `ref={name}` of the title input, there is no defined `name` variable though, so I'd expect to see a different error. You likely meant to use `ref={title}`.

That said, the implementation is a bit of an anti-pattern. It is generally preferable to use fully controlled inputs using React state and `onChange` handlers on the inputs, or to use uncontrolled inputs and gather the form field values from the `form` element's `onSubmit` event object.

Examples

- Controlled inputs

  ```
  function addBooksForm() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
    const [img, setImg] = useState("");
    const [description, setDescription] = useRef("");
    const [bookLink, setBookLink] = useRef("");

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const data = {
        name: title,
        photo: img,
        des: description,
        link: bookLink,
      };
      dispatch(insertBook(data));

      setTitle("");
      setImg("");
      setDescription("");
      setBookLink("");
    };

    return (
      <div className="w-full  px-4 bg-white ">
        <div className="max-w-[700px] mx-auto">
          <div className="w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col p-4 my-8 rounded-lg ">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center py-4">Insert Book</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-6">
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Title
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md"
                  value={title}
                  onChange={e => setTitle(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Linke of image
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
                  value={img}
                  onChange={e => setImg(e.target.value)}
                  required
                >
                <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
                  Description
                </label>
                <textarea
                  id="message"
                  rows={4}
                  className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm mb-4 text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300"
                  value={description}
                  onChange={e => setDescription(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Linke of book
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
                  value={bookLink}
                  onChange={e => setBookLink(e.target.value)}
                  required
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="text-white bg-[#BDA175] hover:bg-black disabled:bg-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2" 
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```
- Uncontrolled inputs:

  ```
  function addBooksForm() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      const data = {
        name: e.target.title.value,
        photo: e.target.photo.value,
        des: e.target.description.value,
        link: e.target.bookLink.value,
      };
      dispatch(insertBook(data));

      e.target.reset();
    };

    return (
      <div className="w-full  px-4 bg-white ">
        <div className="max-w-[700px] mx-auto">
          <div className="w-full shadow-xl flex flex-col p-4 my-8 rounded-lg ">
            <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center py-4">Insert Book</h2>
            <form onSubmit={handelSubmit}>
              <div className="mb-6">
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Title
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md"
                  name="title"
                  required
                />
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Linke of image
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
                  name="photo"
                  required
                >
                <label className="block mb-2 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 ">
                  Description
                </label>
                <textarea
                  id="message"
                  rows={4}
                  className="block p-2.5 w-full text-sm mb-4 text-gray-900 bg-gray-50 rounded-lg border border-gray-300"
                  name="description
                  required
                />
                <label className="block mb-2 text-l font-medium text-gray-900">
                  Linke of book
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  className="block w-full p-4 mb-4 text-gray-900 border border-gray-300 rounded-lg bg-gray-50 sm:text-md "
                  name="bookLink"
                  required
                />
                <button
                  type="submit"
                  className="text-white bg-[#BDA175] hover:bg-black disabled:bg-blue-300 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 mr-2 mb-2" 
                >
                  Submit
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked, but another error occurred
( Unexpected token 'T', "TypeError:"... is not valid JSON )

Comment: @Anwar Seems like a separate issue since this post doesn't appear to have anything to do any JSON data, ...perhaps in a network request you are sending to a backend, or something in the response payload? It may be better to create a new post for this new specific issue. If you do, please feel free to ping me in a comment here with a link to the post and I can take a look when available.

Comment: Thank you again, here is the link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77649112/unexpected-token-t-typeerror-is-not-valid-json-with-nextjs